# Is this a good place for a clustered index for ms sql 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database table that stores the file path of a file and a revision number.

- Each file has a revision number associated with it.
- Each file has about 10 revisions at any given time.
- Every day a new revision gets created for every file
- Every day the oldest revision gets removed for every file.
- There are about 100 Million files

Please trust that the above needs to be this way, this is a scaled down example of my real problem.

Would a good clustered index for this table be 'revision number' since I am always removing all revisions that are close to each other? And then I'm also adding all new revisions the same revision each day for each file.

Comment: Are revision numbers globally unique, or only unique to each document?

Comment: If you revision numbers are globally unique (ex. UTC time) the index you are planning to create will not help to increase performance.

Comment: @bahadir: they are unique to the revision table but they are shared for every file on a certian day.  So for example today all files are revision 10301

Answer (score 2):

According to [Kimberly L. Tripp's Blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/Ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-Clustered-Index-Debateagain!.aspx), a clustered index should be:

- unique
- narrow
- static
- ever increasing

So, let's evaluate your proposed 'revision number' in light of these criteria.

- **unique** - This will depend on your answer to Ed Harper's comment. If it's not unique on it's own, it seems like the combination of revision number + file would be.
- **narrow** - Assuming revision is something like an integer, you're OK here. If you need to go to revision number + file for uniqueness, and if the file has an ID that's another integer, you're still OK.
- **static** - It sounds like a revision is never changed once it is created, so you're good here.
- **Ever increasing** - I'm reading between the lines a little bit now, but I think your new revisions are probably created in this way.

In conclusion, depending on the uniqueness of revision numbers, it seems like either revision number or revision number + file ID would be a good choice for the clustered index.

Comment: Please see my reply above.  It is not unique and the revision number is an int.

Comment: Then, assuming you have a file ID (integer) to work with, I'd cluster on Revision Number + File ID.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Joe Stefanelli's answer, I'd add:

- How is the table being used?
- Is it merely a dump or log of activity, is it used for OLTP purposes (lookup a few rows at a time), is it used for OLAP-like activity (read many, many rows at a time)?
- Is performanace critical (must retrieve rows in microsecond time) or secondary (say for end-of day reports)?

Since you only get one clustered index, I'd tailor the clustered index based on these answers so that is best supports system requirements. Some ideas:

If it's a daily log that is rarely if ever queried, a clustered index on only RevisionNumber would be adequate.

If you report on all files loaded on a given day, the clustered index on RevisionNumber would be ideal.

If you need to look up *individual* files with any kind of frequency or expediency, that index would suck since, if I've got it right, there'd be 100,000,000 rows (files) for each RevisionNumber -- but a simple non-clustered index on FileName, or FileName + RevisionNumber, would cover that (but see the next idea).

For fast lookups, FileName, FilePath, or FilePath + FileName could be painfully long strings to index. Adding a column (or a persisted calculated column) for checksum(FileWhatever) and indexing on that could save a lot of time. Queries would have to look something like:

```
SELECT FullFileName, Plus, Other, Columns
 from FileTable
 where RevisionNumber = @TargetRevision
  and ChecksumColumn = checksum(@TargetFullFileName)
  and FullFileName = @TargetFullFileName
```

Lastly, if you're really adding *and* dropping about 100,000,000 rows every day, I'd serious look into table partitioning, with the partition based on RevisionNumber.